# Drupal 7 Webform : How to display/hide some fields based on other select option fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-webform

I am using Drupal -7 and webform .. I need to show/hide different fields based on on select option.
for eg. select option "Project type"

if I select "Project type" as A => I want to display field1, field2 and select-option3

if I select "Project type" as B => I will display only field3, field4 and select-option4

rest all fields will be displayed in both the cases.

I cant use webform conditional as it doesn't work with select Other.
Can anyone help me with the code either "Hook" or "Markup" field in webform.

Comment: take a look also to [Conditional Fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into the [Webform Conditional](http://drupal.org/project/webform_conditional) module.  There's a demo here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7uxfqJr6K6U which can show you what it's capable of to verify that this is what you're looking for.

Comment: @mmc: Actually I had seen this earlier but it is not compatible with the "Select (or Other)" module. and I am using this module already.

Comment: can you suggest some other way of doing it?

Comment: @rohit bhatnagar: other way is to write your own javascript to toggle showing/hiding the displays according to your logic.

Comment: Well if you are familiar with the Form API #states system in D7 you can do it in your own custom module. Have a look at: http://randyfay.com/states for a gentle introduction.

Comment: @mnc: how do I add my own java script in webform code? can you please guide me?

Comment: @mikewink: I have a custom module of mine. but I dont know How can I change one component based on other.. can you give me some code snippet for a scenario where component "task_title" is hidden based on selecting "BAU" in "type_of_work" select.